# In-app update giving UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE whereas on playstore I can see update button

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app, in-app-update, app-update

I have integrated in-app feature but it is returning UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE whereas on playstore I can see update button and my app version is lower than playstore version.

```
fun updateAppIfAvailable(context: Context) {
        val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "Update available " + appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() + "  " + appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE) + "  " + appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {

                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, context as Activity, RequestCodes.REQUEST_CODE_IN_APP_UPDATE)
            }
        }
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception Update available " + it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make sure that the versionCode is lower than the one available on playstore. Is that the case?

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous version is lesser than playstore version theredore I am getting update button on playstore but in app I am getting UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: Did you resolve this?